# Rails app server running on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I am running my Rails app using "Rails s" in my web server and it says it's running on `http://0.0.0.0:3000` but I cannot seem to find how to access this in my browser.

Is there a way to find a domain name associated with this IP address and port?

Comment: No I can't. This is on web server not on my local computer

Comment: How did you ssh into the server? That's likely the IP or domain name to use.

Comment: You said CentOS, so executing `ifconfig` remotely should give you information about the network interface it's running on, including the IP address.  If you really need a domain name, `dig -x (ip_address_you_found)` should find it if it has one; otherwise just manually add an entry to your local `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: By default webrick only accepts requests from localhost. You should change your rails server

Answer (score 0):

When you say its in your web server, do you mean:

1. The PC you are currently using: **type the address it gave you**
2. A PC on your network: **type the IP of that PC in place of the `0.0.0.0` part `http://192.168.0.2:3000`**

Comment: Matt this is on the web server not PC. It's Cent OS

Comment: How do you control the web server, how did you start the server. Did you use an SSH client? If so, you gave that client an address to connect to, use the same address in your browser, with `:3000` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try location

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

it's dafault rails localhost page

Comment: OP said it's on a remote system and not on his local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Port 3000 should be open on your server in this case.

But it's strongly recommended to not use default rails server (Webrick) on production servers.
Instead you should use [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) + nginx (apache). Or use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Unicorn](http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/) or [Puma](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/) instead Webrick (with apache or nginx as web server fo static).

Comment: Maybe I'd just use Heroku?